# Ошибка "Приведение строки к типу "Double" при построении запроса

Tags: sql, select, vb.net

Программно создаю запрос для отправки в базу. Запрос выбирает записи по условию `Filt`, и среди записей с номером строки в диапазоне от `Num` до `NumEnd`:

```
Dim Num As Integer = Args("Num")
Dim NumEnd As Integer = Num + 30

Query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT [RecordID],[PageName],[Lang],[ControlName],[ControlValue],[StatusID],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by [RecordID]) AS RowNum FROM [dbo].[core_Multilang] where ControlValue like '%" + Filt + "%') as x WHERE RowNum>'" + Num + "' and RowNum<'" + NumEnd + "'; "
```

Но при создании запроса возникает ошибка:

```
Приведение строки "SELECT * FROM (SELECT [RecordID]" к типу "Double" является недопустимым.
```

Как её исправить?

Comment: Какого типа Filt?

Comment: @msi, Flit типа String - из-за него проблем нет. Сначала данный запрос был только с параметром Flit, вместо Num и NumEnd были числа. И запрос работал. Когда числа заменил на Num и NumEnd - возникла указанная ошибка

Comment: @Icnw, тогда попробуйте убрать кавычки вокруг Num и NumEnd.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаток VB, но судя по всему интерпретатор считает что Query должен иметь тип Double. Соответственно необходимо явно указать что тип String. Както так:

```
Dim Num As Integer = Args("Num")
Dim NumEnd As Integer = Num + 30

Dim Query As String = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT [RecordID],[PageName],[Lang],[ControlName],[ControlValue],[StatusID],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by [RecordID]) AS RowNum FROM [dbo].[core_Multilang] where ControlValue like '%" + Filt + "%') as x WHERE RowNum>'" + Num + "' and RowNum<'" + NumEnd + "'; "
```